# Efficient shift invariant feature transform for text

Tags: algorithm, text, transformation, sift

**Edit**

There are 3 continuous bitstreams. At one time one starts reading them. After some time one stops and has now 3 very long strings the same length.

Those 3 strings should contain the sent message somewhere in between. Except for the message random bits are sent.

The objective would now be, to find out how to overlay the 3 strings to further perform any error correction.

```
hfkasjkfhjs<<this is a string><hjaksdf
jkdf::this is b strimg>>iowefjlasfjoie
jfaskflsjdflf<<this is a  tring>>oweio
```

here is a simple example. Now what I want is this

```
<<this is a string><
::this is b string>>
<<this is a  tring>>
```

now I can just use majority voting and get the correct sequence

```
<<this is a string>>
```

How would I achieve this efficiently?

Comment: Smells like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viterbi_decoder (or do you mean the input can contain indels)

Comment: Would perhaps calculating Hamming distances for the different shift candidates work?

Comment: @joop: I am not really sure what the viterbi decoder does, I read a little bit but it seems I would need far more background knowledge to comprehend. Still it says it is used for specially encoded streams using the viterbi algorithm that tries to find a markov model which is far more complex than a bitstream. Or is there a simplification of that one working for me?x

Comment: @biziclop: For the hamming distance it just calculates the deviation, but imagine several bitstreams having random bits at first until the a starting sequence (which can have flipped bits as well) tells where to start listening. Problem is here that there should be lots of similar information somewhere in the middle of the stream but less in the beginning and end as this stream usually is continuous, when you cut out a big enough chunk you may then try to search for starting sequences but they may be broken which leads to my problem again where I don't know how to overlay them to correct that

Comment: You are not very specific about your problem. In particular is is not clear if loss of syncronisation is a possible cause of disagreement. Another possibility is the insertion/deletion of random (stretches of) bits/characters in the stream. For DNA alignment/assemblage, there is a whole family of algorithms to deal with this sort of problems. (google for BLAST) Note: finding the start/synchronising looks like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CpG_site

Comment: `specially encoded streams using the viterbi algorithm that tries to find a markov model which is far more complex than a bitstream` The Markov model is used to *predict* the next (or current) bit, given the previous bits. IMO there is no theoretical difference between predicting a bit or predicting a *2bit* nucleotide, except for the size of the state space, etc. And these "specially encoded" bitstreams were invented to help the prediction.

Comment: After your update: Rabin-Karp *rolling hash* comes close for a Longest Common Substring problem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_hash Or some n-gram search.

Comment: Is the exact message length known, or does that have to be recovered?

Comment: You have a problem! Two of your messages share a leading `f` before the `<<` sequence: that's a majority vote. So the correct message is `f<<this is a  tring>>`.

Comment: The second string contains `strimg`, not `string` as you later claim.

Comment: @Kaz: you are certainly right that the f is in the string, but that is not a problem for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exploratory programming in [TXR](http://nongnu.org/txr) Lisp:

Contents of `fuzz-extract.tl`:

```
(defun fuzz (str)
  (window-map 1 "  "
              (do if (memql #\X @rest)
                #\X #\space)
              str))

(defun correlate (str1 str2 thresh)
  (let ((len (length str1))
        (pat (mkstring thresh #\X)))
    (each ((offs (range* 0 len)))
      (let* ((str2-shf `@[str2 offs..:]@[str2 0..offs]`)
             (str2-dshf `@{str2-shf}@{str2-shf}`)
             (raw-diff (mapcar [iff eql (ret #\X) (ret #\space)]
                               str1 str2-dshf))
             (diff (fuzz raw-diff))
             (pos (search-str diff pat)))
        (if pos
          (let ((rng (+ (r^ #/X+/ pos diff) #R(-2 2))))
            (if (< (from rng) 0)
              (set rng 0..(to rng)))
            (return-from correlate [str1 rng])))))))

(defun count-same (big-s lit-s offs)
  (countq t [mapcar eql [big-s offs..:] lit-s]))

(defun find-off (big-s lit-s)
  (let ((idx-count-pairs (collect-each ((i (range 0 (- (length big-s)
                                                       (length lit-s)))))
                           (list i (count-same big-s lit-s i)))))
    (first [find-max idx-count-pairs : second])))

(defun extract-from-three (str1 str2 str3 : (thresh 10))
  (let* ((ss1 (correlate str1 str2 thresh))
         (ss2 (correlate str2 str3 thresh))
         (ss3 (correlate str3 str1 thresh))
         (maxlen [[mapf max length length length] ss1 ss2 ss3])
         (pad (mkstring (trunc maxlen 2) #\space))
         (buf1 `@pad@ss1@pad`)
         (off1 (find-off buf1 ss2))
         (buf2 `@{"" off1}@ss2`)
         (off2 (find-off buf1 ss3))
         (buf3 `@{"" off2}@ss3`))
    (mapcar (do cond
              ((eql @1 @2) @1)
              ((eql @2 @3) @2)
              ((eql @3 @1) @3)
              (t #\space))
            buf1 buf2 buf3)))
```

Interactive session:

```
$ txr -i fuzz-extract.tl
1> (extract-from-three
     "hfkasjkfhjs<<this is a string><hjaksdf"
     "jkdf::this is b strimg>>iowefjlasfjoie"
     "jfaskflsjdflf<<this is a  tring>>oweio")
"             f<<this is a string>>  "
2> (trim-str *1)
"f<<this is a string>>"
```

Comment: I actually worked through the code and wrote it in another language. It works now perfectly.